# Move ImageView around inside RelativeLayout

Tags: android

I need to move an ImageView (or anything else, for that matter) around inside a RelativeLayout. Does any one know the proper way to do this?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? What does "move around" mean?

Comment: Like, move its x\y coordinates. For example, if you had an image which was larger than the screen resolution and you wanted to be able to drag it around to look at the parts which were off screen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Makesure *ImageView*'s **layout_height** and **layout_width** is set to **fill_parent**. Then do:

To move a view, use *Matrix*. It is very handy.

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

matrix.reset();

matrix.postTranslate(x, y);

imageview.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
imageview.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

Comment: remember to set the ImageView android:scaleType="matrix" in xml if you plan to use this and return the view to the center/start position (as with a joystick handle), else it will get offset if its not set.

Answer (score 2):

this I found worked:

```
imageview.layout(l,t,r,b);
```

Answer (score 1):

mImageView.scrollBy(xOffset, yOffset);

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy. You can implement `onTouchListener` event of any control you want and set its x, y position like make a new `LayoutParams` set its x, y and assign to view as `view.setLayoutParam(layoutParams);` it will drag the View.