# ImageView and set position

Tags: android

I have imageView in activity. How I can set position this imageView in my activity. I know how I can do this in xml file but I want to do this in activity, because I have onTouch method where I get coordinates where I clicked and I want to draw this images in this coordinates.

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660150/move-imageview-around-inside-relativelayout

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@edi233--

I think you can get touch x & y so that you can calculate top margin & left margin. I think (0,0) will be left top corner so if you touch (100,75) you need to set margins of image view to top - 75 & left to 100

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

params.setMargins(100,75, 0,0);
// OR
params.topMargin= 100;

image.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: "setMargins" is not available in all versions of LayoutParams. It is availble in RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.

Answer (score 3):

use the [View.layout(int, int, int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#layout%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) in order to set its position