# How to add button to top left corner in an android shape?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-shapedrawable

I have created a shape in my `Android` project and I would like to add a button on the top left corner.

This is my shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />
    <padding android:left="2dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="2dp"
        android:bottom="1dp" />
</shape>
```

I add a screenshot to have more explication :

[image]

I want the cross at the top left corner of my rect but as you can see it's not that actually :(.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: would you please rephrase your question? or please post some screenshot for better understanding?

Comment: What you have tried to add button on the top left corner of shape?.

Comment: actually i try to take the coordonnate of the imageview but it not works

Comment: Add a cross button some pix left and top to your shape position. if you add a shape at 100,100 then try to add button at 70,70 and adjust it as you want.

Comment: Can you please share your effort then it may be useful to fix/track your issue.

Comment: you want my java code? because my xml is posted in my question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41192/discussion-between-homo-sapiens-and-maxime-vince)

Answer (score 0):

After a Long Discussion with you, I just add a `Shape` `Right and Below` to `crossImageButton` in `Relativelayout` as a parent.

Here i have shared the code, Do the needed modification as your requirement

```
        RelativeLayout parent = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.parent);
        ImageButton ib = new ImageButton(getApplicationContext());
        ib.setId(1);
        ib.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cross_button);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ib.setLayoutParams(lp);
        parent.addView(ib);

        ImageView iv = new ImageView(getApplicationContext()); 
        iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myshape);
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(50,50);
        lp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, ib.getId());
        lp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, ib.getId());
        iv.setLayoutParams(lp1);
        parent.addView(iv);
```

Comment: thank you but what i had you said, i move my imageview with my finger, and i'm not sure that it's possible with a relative layout

Comment: No problem What kind of container you are use. Refer @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398057/  and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660150/

Comment: If i use your example, i will use a relative layout. however with your links, it's just to move view not layout. is it the same work?