# Animation of moving one view in place of another view

Tags: java, android, animation, layouttransition

I'm trying to move one view with **animation** to another, but so far nothing works. I have two views in **RelativeLayout** and one view should replace the other as follows:
I try it but it doesnt work:

```
TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, second_view.getX(), 0, second_view.getY());
view.startAnimation(translateAnimation);
```

[view_screenshot_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHQcJ.png)

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow :)
 For me your question isn't clear enough. Which Framework do you use? What have you already tried to do in order to solve the problem?

Comment: Anyway after seen you have added tags :) Does this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660150/move-imageview-around-inside-relativelayout

Comment: If it's not compulsory to use Relative layout then you can use Constraint Layouts. See this link: https://robinhood.engineering/beautiful-animations-using-android-constraintlayout-eee5b72ecae3

Comment: @Remy  i need a specific smooth motion animation. I try this but it doesnt work
TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, second_view.getX(), 0, second_view.getY());
        view.startAnimation(translateAnimation);